# Does Linux enforce memory cgroup limits when the page is touched?

Tags: linux, cgroups

When a process first touches a page and the page is added to the mem_cgroup, if that page puts the mem_cgroup over its limit does the kernel immediately signal quota violation?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel may signal a quota violation when the memory usage of a cgroup exceeds its limit. However, it depends on the implementation and configuration of the memory management system in use. The exact behavior may vary, and the kernel may not immediately signal a quota violation as soon as the limit is exceeded. It might signal a violation after a certain amount of memory usage or when reclaiming memory from the cgroup.